# Database content does not show up Typo3 7.6 Fluid Template

Tags: typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I have a template in the "fileadmin" folder which works fine. But I try to load data inside this html file.

And my `Page` section in the typoscript does look like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.20 {
   templateName = index1
   templateRootPaths.20 = fileadmin/templates/temp/
   table = tt_content
   select {
      selectFields = tt_content.*
      where = colPos = 0
      orderBy = tt_content.sorting
   }
}
```

Does get an error if I remove the `templateName` and the `templateRootPaths`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some lines when copying that code.
there is no `select` property in `FLUIDTEMPLATE`.

if you want to provide some data to your Fluid you need to use the property `variables`:

```
page = PAGE
page.20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.20 {
    templateName = index1
    templateRootPaths.20 = fileadmin/templates/temp/

    variables {
        columnData = CONTENT
        columnData {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                selectFields = tt_content.*
                where = colPos = 0
                orderBy = tt_content.sorting
            }
        }
        // it's the same:
        columnData2 < styles.content.get
    }
}
```

and in your fluid you may use:

```
{columnData->f:format.raw()}
```